# using omniauth's linkedin token in linkedin plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linkedin-api, omniauth

I am using Rails with omniauth plugin to authenticate my application via LinkedIn. Currently, I store the linkedin token which omniauth returns if the user successfully authorize the application:

```
oauth_token"=>"9dd623ad-1e21-2cec-9ede-107e1f8e9e18"
```

I am also using [linkedin](http://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin) plugin to get user's Linkedin information. The problem is; the plugin requires two tokens like the following:

```
client.authorize_from_request(rtoken, rsecret, pin)
c.authorize_from_access("OU812", "8675309")
```

How can I use the omniauth's token in linkedin plugin? Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

OMNIAUTH is for Authentication only. AFAIK you wont be able to use the API with that oauth token alone. Youll still need to send the user off to linked in to authorize API access by doing something like

```
client.request_token(:oauth_callback =>'your callback url')
```

See example here:

http://pivotallabs.com/users/will/blog/articles/1096-linkedin-gem-for-a-web-app

**Update:**

I was able to reuse access token and access secret that I received upon Omniauth callback from LinkedIn and pass it on to **client.authorize_from_access** and got access to LinkedIn API that way. Your mileage may vary as I had to customize linked_in gem to fit my workflow a bit, but once Omniauth gets access token and secret you no longer need to call **client.authorize_from_request**

Comment: good, I have been doing this...but wondering why getting other problems accessing profile method of the client?